# Resultado da mesma conta é diferente no VB e no C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Estou tentando utilizar uma formula que me da o resultado esperado em C#, ao traduzir o código pra VB.NET o resultado é completamente diferente.
Tenho quase certeza de que fiz a tradução corretamente. Será que esqueci de algo?

#### Formula em C#:

```
double x = 199025 / (double)(1 << 19) * 360.0 - 180;
// Resultado: -43.3403778076172
```

Link pra testar online: https://onlinegdb.com/uUuQD8kMG

#### Formula em VB.NET:

```
Dim x as Double = 199025 / CType((1 << 19) * 360.0 - 180, Double)
// Resultado: 0.00105447339908394
```

Link pra testar online: https://onlinegdb.com/02c5RaQTP

Comment: codigos diferentes = resultados diferentes :)  só de curiosidade, como chegou nisso? está validando o framework? ;)

Comment: Se tiver falando da formula, eu tirei do site do OpenStreetMaps pra converter a coordenada X pra Longitude. https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#C.23

Comment: legal, obrigado pela informação

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claramente os códigos são diferentes, então é esperado que o resultado seja diferente também.

Veja que os casts são feitos de forma diferente, mas se fizer o código de forma semelhante os resultados são os mesmos:

C#:

```
double x = 199025 / (double)(1 << 19) * 360.0 - 180;
```

Vb.Net:

```
dim x as Double = 199025 / CDbl(1 << 19) * 360.0 - 180
```

Comment: Funcionou! Eu estava passando tudo para `double` ao invés de só a parte `(1 << 19)`. Existe alguma diferença em utilizar `CType` e `CDbl`?

Comment: sim, o que  na verdade estraga o resultado é o `CType(...., double)`, era só arrumar isso, eu deixei daquele jeito na resposta pq fica fácil de comparar com o código em C# :)

Answer (score 1):

Natan, no caso do C# o seu casting aplicou-se apenas a `(1 << 19)`, enquanto em VB.net a conversão aplicou-se a toda a conta depois da divisão.

Substitua o código C#, adicionando parênteses para que a conversão se dê a todo o resultado:

```
double x = 199025 / (double)((1 << 19) * 360.0 - 180);
```

Caso o resultado do C# seja o correto (`-43.3403778076172`) então corrija o código VB.net, alterando a abrangência da conversão:

```
Dim x as Double = 199025 / CType((1 << 19), Double) * 360.0 - 180
```

Comment: Funcionou! Não tinha me atentado nos parênteses. Muito obrigado